# django rest framework: serializer.JSONField browsable api input initial value set to null (fails validation)?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer.JSONField but when I view the Browsable API the initial value for the form input is set to null. However, this then fails DRF's own validation:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "state" violates not-null constraint
```

Model field:

```
state = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
```

Serializer field:

```
state = serializers.JSONField(label='QB State', required=False, allow_null=False, default=' ')
```

Also tried:

```
state = serializers.JSONField(label='QB State', required=False, default=' ')
state = serializers.JSONField(label='QB State', required=False, default='')
state = serializers.JSONField(label='QB State')
```

How can I prevent the browsable API form pre-populating with the invalid string: null? What am I missing here? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: make the allow_null=True and check and also add null=True to the model field

Comment: Django explicitly states that null on string-based fields should be avoided: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#null

Comment: i can understand that, but as you are using default value the default value will be inserted, so there is no problem with NULL

Comment: Model: state = models.TextField(blank=True, default=' ', null=True)   Serializer: state = serializers.JSONField(label='QB State', required=False, default=' ', allow_null=True)    actually results in NULL being inserted into the db... :(